# how can i use combination of unix signals (like SIGUSR1) with mysql triggers

Tags: mysql

Can i call or notify a C++ application `function` when an `UPDATE` happens in MySQL database using Unix signals like `SIGUSR1` or how can I use combination of Unix signals with MySQL triggers?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not possible. Indded that would be great, it would boost reactive implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. MySQL only communicates over the MySQL socket connection.

Signals are pretty much terrible for IPC, anyway:

- You can't pass any complex information along with a signal; you're usually limited to the signal number and the PID of the process that sent them.
- Their behavior in conjunction with threads is poorly defined.
- Ditto for what happens when you get a lot of signals. (Which would only really be useful if they could carry complex information.)
- They can interrupt system calls, so you may end up having to retry a lot of calls that you ordinarily wouldn't have to, and some rare bugs may end up getting triggered.
- Signal handlers can be triggered at *any time*, so it's not safe to do many things inside a signal handler (most notably, anything that might call `malloc()`).

Basically anything else (sockets, pipes, message queues, netlink...) is better than signals.